# Does async programming make sense for AWS lambda?

Tags: asynchronous, aws-lambda

Asynch programming helps to increase the number of requests a server can handle simultaneously but not necessarily the time to produce the response.

**Since AWS cost depends only on the number of requests and on the execution time, does it make sense to use asynch programming?**

In my case, I have a java lambda that needs to call a single http server. No more than that.

I could either use an http synch or asynch library.
The synch code is more readable. I understand the asynch code is generally better in case of concurrency but probably this not in case of AWS lambda.

Answer (score -2):

What async has to do with AWS Lambda? I think you are mixing up things here.  You can [invoke AWS Lambda both in synch and asynch way](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) (If AWS resources, there are [few limitations on which type of invocation they can do](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction-function.html#java-invocation-options)) . AWS Lambda are really for state-less, short running, scale-able (concurrently) computing requests. How invoke them depends on your need.

Comment: Just be aware that Lambda invocations are time-limited, so if they're waiting for an async callback, they might terminate before receiving it. That looks slightly different from a synchronous call that never returns, from a code design standpoint.

Comment: @MarkReed that is true, I was just trying to clear the air that AWS Lambda has no direction relationship with the specified requirment.